# Dockerfile build error when use apt-get install gcc

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I attempt build a "helloworld" c program to image but a build error occurred when parse `RUN apt-get update & apt-get -y install gcc` with cmd `sudo docker build .`
`Dockerfile` is very simple as this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY hd* ./

RUN apt-get update & apt-get -y install gcc
RUN gcc ./hd.c -o hellodocker

ENTRYPOINT ./hellodocker
```

worker dir as this:

```
$ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep  6 02:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Sep  5 23:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  386 Sep  6 02:38 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   81 Sep  6 01:35 hd.c
```

hd.c is:

```
$ cat hd.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) { printf("hello docker\n"); }
```

**Error encounter when use `sudo docker build .`**:

```
$ sudo docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 13.31 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> bd3d4369aebc
Step 2 : COPY hd* ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 348a98d816f0
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update & apt-get -y install gcc
 ---> Running in 205cd4de149c
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package gcc
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update & apt-get -y install gcc' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

The tips is very rough, does someone know what's the matter it is? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single ampersand will background a task, which means the `install` starts running before the `update` is finished.

```
apt-get update & apt-get -y install gcc
               ^
```

You want `&&`

```
apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `apt-get update && apt-get -y install gcc` with double '&'